# CGAL - How to retrieve faces and egdes vertices properties after Delaunay triangulation?

Tags: c++, qt, cgal

I'm a beginner of CGAL C++ library.
I try to get a simple Delaunay triangulation using a point list (see code below).
It looks working, but I don't know how to get faces and egdes properties (vertices positions).
I have no vertices coordinate properties in Delaunay::Face and Delaunay::Edge,
how can I get it ?

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3<K>  Gt;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<Gt> Delaunay;

typedef K::Point_2 Point_2;
typedef K::Point_3 Point_3;
...
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_compute_Delaunay_triangulation_clicked()
{   
    // Point list to trialgulate (2D)
    std::vector<Point_3> vPts;
    vPts.push_back(Point_3(0,0,0));
    vPts.push_back(Point_3(10,0,0));
    vPts.push_back(Point_3(10,10,0));
    vPts.push_back(Point_3(6,5,0));
    vPts.push_back(Point_3(4,1,0));

    // Triangulation
    Delaunay dt(vPts.begin(), vPts.end());
    cout << "Number of vertices : " << dt.number_of_vertices() << std::endl;
    cout << "Number of faces    : " << dt.number_of_faces() << std::endl;
    Delaunay::Face_iterator itF;
    Delaunay::Face face;
    for ( itF = dt.faces_begin(); itF != dt.faces_end(); ++itF) {
        face = *itF;
        cout << face << endl;
    }
    Delaunay::Edge_iterator itE;
    Delaunay::Edge edge;
    for ( itE = dt.edges_begin(); itE != dt.edges_end(); ++itE) {
        edge = *itE;
        cout << "edge." << endl;
    }
}
```

Program output :

- Number of vertices : 5
- Number of faces    : 5
- 5x empty lines (for the faces)
- 5x "edge." lines (for the edges)

Comment: From a Vertex_handle vh, you can use `vh->point()` to get a point. From a Cell_handle ch and an index i, you can get a Vertex_handle to the i-th vertex with `ch->vertex(i)`. Faces and edges should be represented as tuples of a Cell_handle and the indices of the relevant vertices (or their complement). See the CGAL chapter on 3D Triangulation Data Structure (aka TDS_3).

Comment: Where did you see a "Vertex_handle" and a "Cell_handle" in my program ? Can you give me an example, please ?